# How do I fix a random crash/freeze with audio loop?

Tags: sound, crash

**This problem only happends in GNU/LINUX, not Windows!**

My PC has:

```
CPU: Intel E5200
RAM: 4 GB
GPU: ATI 5450
```

**Causes:**

At first, I thought it was when I opened 20+ tabs on Chromium/Firefox, but now it happends completly randomly. 3 reddit tabs and 1 twitch.

**Issue:**

It freeze the image/keyboard/mouse any interaction so the unique thing you could do is shutdown/restart manually, but the sound still loop with the last sound like Source games when they load anything new.

**Solution:** ? (To be filled)

**Distros:**

I've tried Antergos Gnome (Same issue), Ubuntu 14.04 (Same issue), Ubuntu Gnome (Same issue),Linux Mint Cinnamon (I don't remember well).

And I've search on DDG about this problem but **I couldn't find anything**, I first thought it was a HDD problem but *W10 works fine*.

So that's it, help! And thanks!

EDIT: And **no Crash log**.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me on debian based distributions using an amd ATI graphics card, for the sound problem read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163838/why-does-music-still-loop-when-my-pc-freezes#comment268939_163838) comment

I had no solution for this, but I think it's a GPU problem
Finally switched to arch linux and I haven't any freezes for now